# How to change the addEventListener callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

How do I change the function in addEventListener.

```js
//how do I turn this
button.addEventListener('click', test)
//into this
button.addEventListener('click', test2)
```

I am okay with using js libraries. I have an idea that I can use removeEventListener and then add another event listener but I don't know how to add an eventListener in javascript.

Comment: Have you tried your idea?

Comment: I don't know how to add an evenlistener with javascript only, without having to write the code, so the javascript will generate itself basically

Comment: You think it's going to code itself?

Comment: no so how can I make a function change the addEventListener function, I'm trying to do what is in the code block

Comment: Make a function that accepts the element as one parameter and the listener type as another. Then remove any previous listener before adding the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch EventListeners on the button, you would do exactly as you suggested

```
button.addEventListener("click", test)

button.removeEventListener("click", test)

button.addEventListener("click", test2)
```

An EventListener is essentially one of two things.

1. A function that accepts an event object as an input parameter.
2. An object that has a handleEvent function that accepts an event object as an input parameter.

For test2 to be an EventListener, it would just need to be one of those two things.

**Option 1: As a function**

```
function test2(event) {
    console.log(event)
}

button.addEventListener("click", test2)
```

**Option 2: As an object with a handleEvent function**

```
const test2 = {
    "handleEvent": (event) => {
        console.log(event)
    } 
}

button.addEventListener("click", test2)
```

The documentation to support this can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with delegation, just assign each time the function to a variable, then call the variable from callback, like this:

```js
let fn = () => {
  alert('1');
  fn = () => alert('2');
};

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  fn.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">OK</button>
```